# flow item animation trigger by div

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, scrollview

Here is a dummy page I made

```css
#over-flow-menu {
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #666;
}

.grey, .white {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.grey {
  background: #ddd;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="over-flow-menu">MENU</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
```

My goal is to make the **flowing menu**'s background color change
while it scroll into **GREY** section the menu's background color will transform into white, and while it scroll down into the next section of white, the background will turning back to white and so on.

I tried using some plugin like **srollMagic**
but wonder if there's a better why to achieve this goal

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code to your html. It might not be the best solution but works.

```
<script>

window.onscroll = function (e) {
var x = window.scrollY;
var y = x/300;
var z = Math.floor(y);
var t = z%2;
    if(t == 1  ){
     document.getElementById("over-flow-menu").style.background = "#ddd";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("over-flow-menu").style.background = "white";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can achieve this as below script

```js
var divHight = document.getElementsByClassName('grey')[0].offsetHeight;
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var scrollAt = Math.floor(window.scrollY/divHight);
    document.getElementById("over-flow-menu").style.background = (scrollAt%2 == 1? "#ddd": "white") ;
}
```

```css
#over-flow-menu {
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #666;
}

.grey, .white {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.grey {
  background: #ddd;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="over-flow-menu">MENU</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
<div class="grey">GRAY</div>
<div class="white">WHITE</div>
```